# Find difference in text and add formula for next 10 rows

Tags: string, excel, text

I have a **scraper** pulling data from youTube for a slew of URLs. It generates a CSV and depending on the URL it can grab between 15 and 25 rows of data.

What I need to do is separate the URLs into mini sequences and add a total for each URL. I've been going in and doing this manually-scanning the rows and pasting in my ten row chunk of math to strip out the text and add the values up. It's super tedious.

Is there some way to looking at these URLs, they will be the same for 20 rows or so, and then change, when that change happens, on that row add some kind of action/math to do what I need?

Here's a look at that scraped data:

[image]

Comment: Add a new column with something like `=VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(E2," views",""))` to convert your "views" column to a numeric value, then create a pivot table using the URL as the "row" column and sum(your counts here) as "value".

Comment: The hangup is that I only want the first ten rows to count towards the total, so that all the URLs are scored equally (the top 10 videos for each page). You idea is a step in the right direction though.

Comment: Top 10 according to the existing order, or after sorting by number of views?

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams - that's a huge help

Comment: @TimWilliams Is there a particular reason this is downvoted? Especially as "Off Topic"? I don't get it. (Still trying to learn the "why is something bad" rules)

Comment: Generally if a post has only "this is what I need" without any "this is what I tried and this is what happened when I tried it" there could be down-votes/closing.

Answer (score 1):

This will sum only the first 5 rows of each url (assuming they're sorted together)

[image]